# Where do I find the soundtracks and OSTs used in Megalo Box?

Tags: music, megalo-box

So, Megalo Box is a currently airing anime and its music is one of the best I have ever heard in anime. Where do I find the music tracks that have been used in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OST hasn't been released, but it's set to be released on June 27, 2018 as *"Megalo Box" Original Soundtrack*, according to [CDJapan](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/OPCA-1037).

The tracklisting:

> 1. MEGALOBOX
> 2. MEGALOBOX (Sorrow)
> 3. MEGALOBOX (Acoustic)
> 4. Beginning of the Fight
> 5. Battlefield
> 6. Deadlock
> 7. The theme of Gansaku Nanbu
> 8. The theme of Gansaku Nanbu (Sorrow)
> 9. The theme of Gansaku Nanbu (Slow)
> 10. A Day In The Life
> 11. The theme of Sachio
> 12. The theme of Sachio (Sorrow)
> 13. The Slum City feat. COMA-CHI
> 14. The Slum
> 15. The Slum (Night)
> 16. The theme of Bangaichi
> 17. Get up
> 18. The theme of Yukiko Shirato
> 19. The theme of Yukiko Shirato (Slow)
> 20. The theme of Yukiko Shirato (Fanfare)
> 21. The theme of Fujimaki
> 22. The theme of Aragaki
> 23. The theme of Aragaki (Piano ver.)
> 24. Heartwarming
> 25. The theme of Mikio Shirato
> 26. The theme of Mikio Shirato (Slow)
> 27. Lost In Grief (Deep)
> 28. Conflict
> 29. Change The Situation 1
> 30. Change The Situation 2
> 31. The theme of Yuri
> 32. The theme of Yuri (Slow)
> 33. Darkness
> 34. Confession
> 35. Resolution
> 36. Resolution (Slow)
> 37. Drive
> 38. Gearless Joe feat. COMA-CHI
> 39. Megalonia News Network
> 40. Enter The Arena
> 41. The theme of Glen Burroughs
> 42. The theme of Pepe Iglesias
> 43. We are Bangaichi feat. Sachio
> 44. The Beast feat. COMA-CHI
> 45. The Beast (Instrumental)
> 46. Celebration
> 47. The Ending